# How to change scrolling order? md-tabs scrolls before md-toolbar

Tags: android, html, cordova, scrollbar, angular-material

I'm building an app using phonegap.
In my app I have an md-toolbar as an action bar, and below that, md-tabs element.
When I scroll, the first thing to be scrolled is the content of the md-tabs and only when reached the bottom, the md-toolbar scrolls (leaving the tabs at the top).
I would like it to the other way around. The md-toolbar should scroll first, and only then the content (like in the whatsapp app).

```
<md-toolbar>    <!--THIS SCROLLS SECOND-->
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <span>PhotoHut</span>
      <span flex></span>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<div ng-cloak>
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-border-bottom md-stretch-tabs md-swipe-content class="tabs-bar">                
            <md-tab label="photos">

                <!--THIS SCROLLS FIRST-->
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <!-- much content-->
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>

            <!--Some more tabs-->
            <store-tab></store-tab>
            <pay-tab></pay-tab>                 
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
```